# Grabbing Encoded Results from Database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to echo some image paths from a database, but I'm getting the following results in a print_r...

```
[image_directory] => images/catalog/brand/303-products/640/
[images] => a:1:{i:0;s:13:"303030340.jpg";}
```

I'm not sure what the encoding in "images" means but I'm hoping I can easily either grab that image URL or be pointed in the path as to why it's encoded like that and not just the image name.

Thanks!

Comment: `images` looks like a serialised variable. Try `unserialize()` on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a serialized PHP array produced by [`serialize()`](http://php.net/serialize). You can unserialize it with [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/unserialize). *Why* it's this way nobody can tell you but you.

Comment: The why would probably be because multiple filenames can be specified. The unserialized result is an array of filenames.

Comment: @deceze I shall attempt the impossible and tell him *why*. It's an *array* meaning more than one item. Meaning you can have more than one file name there. Such as a gallery.

Comment: No, the real answer for *"why"* is *because _someone_ serialized it this way before putting it into the database.* :P

Comment: No, the real answer for why is because _someone_else_ designed the database column as a text/blog in order for such big strings to fit in there.

Comment: No, the real answer for *"why"* is *because _someone_ did not know how to normalize a database.* :P

Comment: No, the real answer for "why" is because _someone_ designed the serialize function to to output the result like that

Comment: No, the real answer for *"why"* is *because someone designed the PHP serialization format like this and `serialize` implements this specification.*